# Why can't I ask a question on SO that contains <img ...> in a code segment?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

I'm trying to ask a question on SO about JavaScript. My sample code includes `<img ...>` at one point. When I try to post the question, I get this message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: really? you posted the answer to your question.

Comment: Errors are not for decoration. Read them. Fully :)

Answer (score 6):

Try posting it in a codeblock so it isn't interpreted as something to embed an image, but as part of the code you are asking about.

Comment: I suspect this was the problem the user was having...

Comment: use for multilines 4 spaces at the start of each line. eg "\n    <!DOCTYPE HTML>" The \n meaning you need a blank line before the code, The other option would be `\`<!DOCTYPE HTML>\`` But again this would only work if you want to view the raw code and don't wish to display the image or <video> for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Because new users aren't allowed to post images.  You need to earn 10 point of reputation to post images.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a link to an image though...